# Error : Missing $ inserted in \begin{cases} and basic questions?

Tags: errors

```
\newpage

\section*{Basics}
\begin{definition} [\textsc{Pochhammer}-Symbol]
        The \textsc{Pochhammer-Symbol} with $(a;q)_n$
         is an expression in combinatorics, which is defined as 
    \begin{cases}
            (a;q)_n:=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^k)  & \text{$k>0$} \\\\[2ex]
                        (a;q)_0=1  & \text{$k=0$}
        \end{cases}
        The symbol also.....
\end{definition}
```

Hello,
I want to write my Bachelor thesis and need help at the beginning :´D There are three things , which drive me crazy:

I get the error :
Missing $ inserted \begin{cases}
Missing $ inserted \end{cases}

how can I solve it ?

My defintion appears as "Definition 0.1" but I would like 1.1, can I solve it, without nummering the chapter ?

I want my chapter in the center and tried "centering" which didn't work. Which command do I have to use here ?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  That's not a section sign in the error; it's a dollar sign, and means that the `cases` environment has to be embedded in a math environment.  This should probably be displayed, as it is too long to be presented in-line.  So wrap it in `\[ ... \]` which will set it as a centered block.  To answer the other questions, more information is needed, particularly what document class you are using.  For best results, show us a complete *small* code example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the parts you want to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

It should be, e.g.,

```
\newpage

\section*{Basics}
\begin{definition} [\textsc{Pochhammer}-Symbol]
        The \textsc{Pochhammer-Symbol} with $(a;q)_n$
         is an expression in combinatorics, which is defined as 
\[
    \begin{cases}
            (a;q)_n:=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-aq^k)  & \text{$k>0$} \\\\[2ex]
                        (a;q)_0=1  & \text{$k=0$}
        \end{cases}
\]
        The symbol also.....
\end{definition}
```

as `cases` is an environment used in math style. Additionally, I am assuming that you are using a package that defines `cases`.

Comment: +1. I would change `\text{$k>0$}` and `\text{$k=0$}` to`k>0` and `k=0`, though. One should also consider changing `\\\\[2ex]` to `\\[1ex]`.

Comment: @Mico Certainly. `\text` is meaningless in this version, but I have assumed that in a better one it will be `\text{ for $k=0$}` or something similar.